# Amazon API- ItemSearch Operation

Tags: amazon-product-api

Is it possible to retrieve only one item information from amazon api using ItemSearch operation?

Now I am getting 10 records for a book search.

I'd like to see only single item-information. For example: for a C# book search, I'd like to see only one complete information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the details of only one product, then you must perform [**ItemLookup**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html).

Given an `Item identifier`, the `ItemLookup` operation returns some or all of the item attributes, depending on the response group specified in the request.

`ItemLookup` supports many response groups. Response groups return product information, called item `attributes`. Item attributes include **product reviews, variations, similar products, pricing, availability, images of products, accessories, and other information**.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I don't want to use ItemLookup, with ItemSearch operation only, can i retrieve single book information.

Comment: Your link for ItemLookup doesn't work anymore?